# extjs : How to access a variable in ajax request success, outside the ajax request

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I want to use the value of `var ajaxRe` which is in the ajax request success,
outside the ajax request, but the value is `undefined`. I want to use the response to load data in a grid,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : myUrl,
        params : {
            myParamList
        },
        success : function(re,action) {
            var ajaxRe = re.responseText;
            ...
            var respArr = ..;
        },
        failure : function(form,action) {
            console.log("fail");
        }
});
```

when I print `grid.getStore()` within success, the grid contains the data I need, but it is not being displayed,

I am setting data in the grid's store within success, and accessing the grid outside.

```
success : function(re,action) {
    that.editorGrid.getStore().data = respArr;  
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Like mentioned below, use a store with a proxy and bind it to your grid. If you need to later access the store's data, use `Ext.StoreManager.lookup('theStoreId')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is in correct format  try below

```
that.editorGrid.getStore().loadData(respArr);
```

If you want apply proxy reader to load data use

```
that.editorGrid.getStore().loadRawData(respArr);
```

One other way is to reconfigure store and bind that store to grid

```
    var store = Ext.create('Model', {
            autoLoad: true,
            data: responseJson,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        });
 that.editorGrid.bindStore(store);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Saki that you should use a store to fill the grid, so if it doesn't reload, there is probably another problem.

Anyway, to answer your question : just define ajaxRe outside of the ajax request :

```
var ajaxRe = '';
Ext.Ajax.request({
   ... 
   ajaxRe = re.responseText;
   ...
});
```

But be careful that you may try to access the variable before the value is actually set.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a separate request to populate a (grid) store. Define a proxy on the store and Ext takes care of the rest. You can also take a look at [this example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#writable-grid), see the code and analyze what data travels to the server and back.

Comment: I have used grid with store proxy, but I was trying store reload and that did not work. So I wanted to try with ajax request.

Comment: How did you try "store reload"? To initially load the store you only need configure it with autoLoad:true. Of course, for the store to really load, the server response must abide by some rules. See the example in the answer to learn how the server should respond.